Can a thermistor's heat capacity be calculated using the still air thermal time constant and dissipation constant? (using $C = τ·h·A$)
Thermistor data sheets typically state the thermal time constant in still air and the dissipation constant in still air.
For a body heating or cooling, the thermal time constant can be calculated as $\tau = \dfrac{C}{h \cdot A}$, where $C$ is the heat capacity, $h$ is the heat transfer coefficient and $A$ is the surface area. Therefore:
$$C = \tau \cdot h \cdot A \ .$$
The term $h \cdot A$ gives the same units as thermal conductance ($G$), in $\text{W/K}$, which is the amount of power being transferred per Kelvin difference in temperature, so can we say:
$$C = \tau \cdot G \ .$$
The units of the dissipation constant are the same as thermal conductance ($\text{W/K}$), and since all the power is transferred to the environment as heat, it makes me think I may be able to calculate the heat capacity using just the still air time constant and the still air dissipation constant.
Is that right? If not, why not?
